# Audio not working in win 10 in virtualbox (virtualbox 5.1.2 + guest additions, macbook pro early 2011, osx el capitan)

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, macbook-pro, speakers, microphone

I installed Windows 10 in virtualbox on my macbook and now speakers and mic are not working with win 10. My problem is mainly with speakers.

Comment: Try to use the Audio Driver ICHA97, boot Windows with Driver Signature enforcement disabled and install the Audio drivers from intel.

Comment: How to do that? I can change driver but i do not know how to do the other thing.

Answer (score 17):

had a similar problem (audio cracking/not working);
what worked for me (Xubuntu as Host, VirtualBox 5.2.14) I found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134018/microphone-in-windows-10-in-virtualbox) marked off-topic:

1. VirtualBox - open the settings for your Windows 10 machine
2. Go to Audio > Audio Controller, change to 'ALSA Audio Driver' and "ICH AC97" as Controller
3. [Boot your Windows 10 machine and disable driver signature enforcement](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/)
4. Go to [Realtek website](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-ac-97-audio-codecs-software), download and install the AC'97 audio codec/driver for Vista/7 ("Vista/Win7 (32/64 bits) Driver only (ZIP file)") onto your Windows 10 machine (run setup.exe)
5. Reboot Windows 10

Comment: I don't see an ALSA audio driver in my settings, but I do have ICH AC97. Should CoreAudio work?

Installing the AC'97 codec hasn't had any effect.

Comment: Here's the link without having to give RealTek your email... `https://realtek-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/6305_vista_win7_pg537.zip`

Comment: Worked for me. I found that for Skype, I had to further select the Microphone (Realtek AC '97 Audio) from a dropdown list-- originally, it was set to "Phone Line".

Comment: For step 3 open command prompt and run `bcdedit /set testsigning on` and then restart the machine.

Comment: I have Windows 10 as a host, didn't fix the cracking issue.

Comment: Didn't work either on Ubuntu 20.04 as host and Win10 guest with Virtualbox 6.1

Comment: This went took me from no sound to crackling sound. But only selecting "Intel HD Audio" actually works. But is horrendously slow.

Answer (score 3):

Combination that worked for me (Ubuntu Host, Win10 guest)  :
In Win10

- install realtek driver
  In virtualbox
- Host audio driver : PulseAudio
- Audio Controller: Intel HD Audio

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work by:

1. Follow the [answer by definitely undefinable](https://superuser.com/a/1338549/1263618)
2. Before rebooting, opening the windows device manager (`Win + R`, enter `devmgmt.msc` and press `Enter`)
3. Find the `Multimedia Audio Controller` in one of the categories. It should be displayed as missing a driver (yellow exclamation mark in the icon)
4. Right-click on the listing and select `Update Driver Software...`
5. Select `Browse my computer for driver software`
6. Browse to the unzipped Realtek driver folder. Make sure `Include Subfolders` is checked. Press `Next`.
7. Select `Install this driver software anyway`.
8. Reboot the VM.

I furthermore had to change the Virtualbox settings back to `PulseAudio`, as I am using this on my Ubuntu 18.04 setup.